# delete table row with effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

On [this page](http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/artistSubscription/list), if you click the unsubscribe button on the first row (Madonna), the rows beneath slide up reasonably nicely. But if you then delete the new first row (Radiohead), the image on the remaining row (U2) jumps unpleasantly to the left after the row moves into position. The function that's called to perform the table row deletion is:

```
SF.deleteRow = function(selector) {
    $(selector)
        .children('td, th')
        .animate({ paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0 })
        .wrapInner('<div />')
        .children()
        .slideUp('slow', function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });
};
```

If I remove all the padding in the table cells, this problem disappears, but then I have no padding.....

Is there any way to fix this problem? Alternatively, is there another effect I can apply when deleting a table row that avoids this problem (I don't want the row to just disappear instantly when the Unsubscribe button is clicked).

Comment: Both slide nicely when I visit your link

Comment: I see this behaviour in FF8 and Chrome15

Comment: @MattBall I have the browser cache disabled (with the web developer toolbar)

Comment: i do see a slight (maybe 5 pixles) jump to the left. FF7 on Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: This is inherant to the default behavior of a table's column. It reduces/expands its width with the contet. Try giving you first column a fixed size. You can also change your `<table>` for a `<ul>` which will be easier to style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jump you mentioned happens because first column shrinks when longer text "Radiohead" is removed and shorter text "U2" is the only factor defining the cell width in the first column. This problem can be solved by having fixed column widths in your table.

Comment: +2 ;) That's the only reasonable answer!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to make it with only div's and not with a table.. then u can do it easly like:

```
<style>
    .row {
        float: left;
        width: 990px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
        .row  .col {
            float: left;
            width: 490px;
        }
            .row  .col.first {
                width: 200px;
            }
            .row  .col.last {
                width: 300px;
            }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    [...]
    SF.deleteRow = function(selector) {
        $(selector)
            .find('.row')
            .animate({ height: 0 },"fast", "linear", function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
    };
    [...]
</script>

<div class="row even">
    <div class="col first">[....]</div>
    <div class="col">[....]</div>
    <div class="col last">[....]></div>
</div>
<div class="row odd">
    <div class="col first">[....]</div>
    <div class="col">[....]</div>
    <div class="col last">[....]></div>
</div>
<div class="row even">
    <div class="col first">[....]</div>
    <div class="col">[....]</div>
    <div class="col last">[....]></div>
</div>
<div class="row even">
    <div class="col first">[....]</div>
    <div class="col">[....]</div>
    <div class="col last">[....]></div>
</div>
```

It is just an example. Because of the overflow on the `row` class is hidden it will show nothing when the height is 0.

If you just wanna use a table it will be a little bit harder!

This answer is just a suggestion to use div's instead of table.. i also like to use css floats because its easier to make animations on elements then non-floated objects(is my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

Th​at so​lution se​ems aw​fully co​mplicated... wh​y no​t ju​st se​t the overflow of the container to "hidden" and shrink the height of the container...

Edit:: Thankyou @Derek for pointing out to me the border remains... Got me looking at my code again and noticed a but. The callback function should be `$(this).remove();` and that is all.

[see here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/kj2qC/2/) for an example.

Comment: the border is still there after pressing "delete".

Comment: Your suggestion works beautifully on the jsfiddle page, but for some reason it doesn't work on my page. I can't see any difference between the two, can you?

Comment: well, a bit of css tweaking would be involved.. I would assume. hard to tell unless I tried to implement it into your markup.

Comment: @Derek I have updated the post... [can be seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/kj2qC/2/)

Comment: My limited understanding of .remove() in jQuery was the culprit